# The meaning of <= vs. => in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm relatively new to Haskell; what does the `<=` syntax represent and what is the difference between `<=` and `=>`?  Examples of both would be helpful.

Comment: `<=` is just the `less than or equal` operator/function, I suppose?

Comment: In Haskell I know that => differs from -> but I'm not sure how.  I've seen both <= and => used in notation

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The two are completely unrelated; they just seem related because of ASCII. It makes more sense if you look at their Unicode equivalents:

- `=>` is an arrow: `⇒`. It's used to specify constraints in type signatures:

  ```
  Eq a => a -> a -> Bool
  ```

  The `Eq a =>` in the above signature means that the type variable `a` can be any type that is an instance of the `Eq` class. That is, any type that either has `deriving (Eq)` or an explicit instance like `instance Eq Type where ...`.

  In function signatures, `->` specifies a normal argument while `=>` specifies *constraints* in the signature. In the above example (`Eq a => a -> a -> Bool`), the function takes two arguments of type `a` and gives us a `Bool`. The `Eq a =>` part is not an explicit argument to the function; it just tells us that `a` must be part of `Eq` (that is, it must be comparable with `==`).
- `<=` is **less than or equal to**. That is, it's `≤`, *not* `⇐`. It's a normal function in the standard library that's part of the `Ord` class:

  ```
  λ> :t (<=)
  (<=) :: Ord a => a -> a -> Bool
  ```

  You can use it in a normal expression:

  ```
  λ> 10 <= 12
  True
  ```

The only reason they seem symmetrical is because the ASCII approximation of `≤` and `⇐` are the same, but that's just a limitation in notation. Otherwise, they're completely unrelated.

You can use the unambiguous Unicode symbols in your code. The `UnicodeSyntax` extension enables using `⇒` for `=>` and the `base-unicode-symbols` package contains Unicode versions of standard library functions including `≤` for `<=`.

Answer (score 4):

They're completely different things.

- `=>` (as well as `->`) is built-in type-level syntax. It's used for denoting constraints. For instance, the signature

  ```
  abs :: Num a => a -> a
  ```

  tells you that the `abs` function takes a value of type `a` and yields a value of the same type, under the condition `a` is a number type (i.e., fulfills the `Num a` constraint). Such a constraint will usually be<sup>†</sup> a *type class*; in this case

  ```
  class Num a where
    ...
  ```

  You can read the `=>` arrow as a sort-of function mapping, too: `abs` first takes the information of *what specific sort of number `a` is* as an “implicit argument”, then one such number as an explicit argument, and only then gives the result.
- `<=` is not syntax, it's just an infix operator that's defined in the standard library. Specifically it's the less-than operator, which mathematicians write **≤**.
  You can look up such operators on [Hayoo](http://hayoo.fh-wedel.de/?query=%3C%3D), no need to ask questions about them.

---

<sup>†</sup><sub>Strictly speaking, a class is not a constraint but a “constraint constructor”, i.e. a type-level function whose *result* is of kind [`Constraint`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/GHC-Exts.html#t:Constraint). For instance, `Num :: * -> Constraint` applied to e.g. `Int :: *` means that `Num Int` is a constraint. (Those are not type signatures but *kind signatures*, i.e. “types of type-level things”.)</sub>